# expanding rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, expand, reindex

I have the following data:

```
product Sales_band  Hour_id sales
prod_1  HIGH           1    200
prod_1  HIGH           3    100
prod_1  HIGH           4    300
prod_1  VERY HIGH      2    100
prod_1  VERY HIGH      5    253
prod_1  VERY HIGH      6    234
```

want to add rows based on the **hour_id** value. hour_id variable can take values from **1 to 10**. So the same data above will be expanded where the hour ids are missing. Dummy output is :(**sales = 0 when missing hour id**)

```
product Sales_band  Hour_id sales
prod_1  HIGH           1    200
prod_1  HIGH           2    0
prod_1  HIGH           3    100
prod_1  HIGH           4    300
prod_1  HIGH           5    0
prod_1  HIGH           6    0
prod_1  HIGH           7    0
prod_1  HIGH           8    0
prod_1  HIGH           9    0
prod_1  HIGH           10   0
prod_1  VERY HIGH      1    0
prod_1  VERY HIGH      2    100
prod_1  VERY HIGH      3    0
prod_1  VERY HIGH      4    0
prod_1  VERY HIGH      5    253
prod_1  VERY HIGH      6    234
prod_1  VERY HIGH      7    0
prod_1  VERY HIGH      8    0
prod_1  VERY HIGH      9    0
prod_1  VERY HIGH      10   0
```

how can I achieve this using python dataframe.

Comment: Should you end up with 10 rows per product and sales band?

Comment: yeah , that should be the ideal final output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['product','Sales_band'])['Hour_id','sales']
         .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Hour_id').reindex(range(1, 11), fill_value=0))
         .reset_index())

   product Sales_band  Hour_id  sales
0   prod_1       HIGH        1    200
1   prod_1       HIGH        2      0
2   prod_1       HIGH        3    100
3   prod_1       HIGH        4    300
4   prod_1       HIGH        5      0
5   prod_1       HIGH        6      0
6   prod_1       HIGH        7      0
7   prod_1       HIGH        8      0
8   prod_1       HIGH        9      0
9   prod_1       HIGH       10      0
10  prod_1  VERY HIGH        1      0
11  prod_1  VERY HIGH        2    100
12  prod_1  VERY HIGH        3      0
13  prod_1  VERY HIGH        4      0
14  prod_1  VERY HIGH        5    253
15  prod_1  VERY HIGH        6    234
16  prod_1  VERY HIGH        7      0
17  prod_1  VERY HIGH        8      0
18  prod_1  VERY HIGH        9      0
19  prod_1  VERY HIGH       10      0
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked. will read more about set_index and reindex .